# ASP.NET MVC, @ in front of grid.GetHtml();

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For an ASP.NET, MVC application, when using `grid` with Razor syntax, why do I need the `@` rightbefore the line `grid.GetHtml();`?

Example -

```
@{
  var grid = new WebGrid(Model);

  @grid.GetHtml();

 }
```

Shouldn't surrounding `grid.GetHtml();` with `@{ }` be enough?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @ is like printing/writing something on the page.

```
grid.GetHtml()
```

will generate the required string but this function doesn't have any idea about printing the generated html. to do this you have to write it like this

```
@grid.GetHtml()
```

There are some helpers where  you don't required to put @ before the statement.

for example

```
Html.RenderPartial()
```

Because MVC writes the generated html to the response stream. Hence here this statement should get included in

> @{
>   }

block in some cases it returns the HTML and we are expected to call print for it using "@"

Answer (score 1):

With @{} you specify that some piece of code should be executed, like declaring the variable "grid".

Now for the second line, without the @, you are only left with a statement that equals a string, which is not even syntactically supported.

While using the @, that line translates to something like:

```
Response.Write(grid.GetHtml());
```

Answer (score 0):

Although what did you did is fully supported in Razor view engine and sometimes can not be done differently it is better to be more specific:

```
@{
   var grid = new WebGrid(Model);   
}

@grid.GetHtml();
```

So to clearly separate the Code from the outputting. I think it make sense for better code/view readability.